# is it possible to overload a php script or to overload server via requesting a php script too much?

Tags: php, performance, scripting

Seems like a long question. I would like a couple of opinions based on general experience.

I use a PHP script to perform several tasks on a server. I was wondering whether it would make a difference if I used, say, three different scripts for three different tasks or if it would not matter at all?

Take into account that I count on something like 2-3k users at a time (evening time, pretty rare) and I still can't afford a server for 300 bucks a month

Answer (score 0):

Using seperate scripts will help you identify issues with each one. You will get error messages and pointers in logs to the exact files.

Also it helps you see which one runs long(est) and if one script crashes it doesn't affect the others. You can more easily monitor which scripts need optimizing.

Just make sure they are not depending on each other.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the purpose of the script and how many concurrent requests there would be made.
Presuming it'll be php-mysql based, I'd say it will mostly depend on the performance of your queries. And so yes, I've known scripts that caused the webserver to fail to give a timeout due to a too heavy load on the MySQL-daemon; even by a select amount of users.

Hope it's of use to you!

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check the php.ini file for your php installation.  The default timeout is 30 seconds, so depending on the load on the server, if your script hasn't finished execution by then, your task will fail.  You can increase this, but be aware it could have an affect on any users patient enough to wait around past 30 seconds for any long executing scripts from the front end.

Other than that, it would be pretty difficult to overload any modern server with just one task during non-peak traffic times.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite common for people to use cronjobs to make PHP multitask. I presume this is what you wanna do. I would just run these scripts as cronjobs and if the load proves heavy for the server then you should probably think about upgrading your network. $300 is a lot for a server, you can get a decent DB server from AWS for like £100 up front and £7 a month using small instances which for a dedicated server base will be fine.

Do note that if you are running the same script multitasking (many crons of the same script running over many hours) you will require something like optimistic lock on your data else you will suffer badly.

Of course if this proves a little too taxing for your server why don't you consider lending out your processing to a better place like iron.io? There are many processing networks out there that will happily and cheaply take your processing load off of you.

Another alternative I have personnally been working on is AWS Spot Instances, what such an awesome creation! I have an auto scaling bunch of micro instances costing me 0.005c per hour and the auto scaling group can work from 0 servers which means when it's not being used it costs me nout. I would definitely say to look into spot instances for processing of your scripts and even maybe holding residual data for those scripts so you are not putting load on the DB. Either way it is a lot cheaper than $300 a month.

But to answer your title, I am running 150 cronjobs every 2 hours on my AWS small instance processing data etc and no, I have not toppled PHP yet or my server, also in CLI mode PHP has no timeout, so if your doing long processing use a command like:

```
php myscript.php
```

To run your processing jobs.